# How do I serve assets when I run ng test using latest angular-cli (beta 15 w/webpack)?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

When I try and run an ng test, all of my modules and components load correctly, but any of the assets I include in `<img>` tags do not render because they're not being served in the /assets folder (like they would in a build or during development using ng serve)

In addition to this, it would be nice to know how to get the global styles.scss/css file to be included in the test, as I can only get these styles to render if I drop the CSS into a component and disable ViewEncapsulation.

I'm on the latest angular-cli webpack release (Beta 15)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 43):

I found the answer!

By default, the karma setup in the angular-cli (webpack) doesn't serve your assets folder by default, but this is very simple to add (once you sift through the documentation)

below is a screenshot of my results and the code I added to get it to work

[image]

To the left you can see my image of Billy Mays is now being served, to the right if you look at the 'file' section of the json, I added the following:

```
{ pattern: './src/assets/**', watched: false, included:false, nocache:false, served:true }
```

I also added a proxies property, to take  the served content (served by default at http://localhost:[karma port number]/base

```
proxies: {
   '/assets/': '/base/src/assets/'
},
```

By specifying `/assets/` as the folder proxy, karma uses the path 
`localhost:[karma port number]/assets` instead of the default.

I'm happy I was able to my own question, and hope this helps some people starting with the angular-cli!

Comment: I know it says to not say thanks, but, thank you! I missed the 'files' section above on first read because it is not marked as code like the 'proxies' section - perhaps you could reformat?

Comment: It work as solution for this bug. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14593

Comment: @ProgrammerInProgress, Do you know how to request a file via http: http.expectOne('./assets/i18n/2/en.json') will this work?

Comment: Very old but very relevant post. Thank you indeed. Btw karma and webpack currently crashes when the proxies part is not set with `UnhandledRejection: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`. See my post https://stackoverflow.com/a/65347089/2416394 which will ultimately link to you, because you solution is much better :)