# [karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined - Angular Unit Testing in CI environment

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, typeerror, gitlab-ci-runner

Our CI/CD pipelines stopped working on the "ng test" job and fails with the following error message:

```
[karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
    at handleRangeHeaders (/builds/......../node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:131:21)
    at processRequest (/builds/......../node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:98:19)
    at ready (/builds/......./node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:53:12)
    at handleRequest (/builds/........../node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:182:5)
    at /builds/............/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:64:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at middleware (/builds/........../node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:63:12)
```

*Added periods to sub out some specific repo names*

We've never had this error before and it worked fine previously. Also oddly enough, it works perfectly when I run it locally. But when the GitLab runners execute it, it fails. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your CI/CD might be type-scanning your node_modules; do you have an

    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]

in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that but still results in the same error. Thanks though!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Was able to figure it out. We were using `node:latest` in our `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and whatever that was pulling down was causing an issue. (It looked to be version 15). So instead of `node:latest`, we set it to `node:14`.

Comment: I can confirm that my tests stopped working with `node v15.2.0`

Comment: Same for me. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: also here @v15.3.0

Comment: having the same issue with v14.15.2. Switching to v14.15.1 works.

Comment: Had this same issue, 14.15.3 is working for me.

Comment: My solution was similar. I deleted the node_modules directory in my project, changed the version of node to an older on (16.13.0) and installed the node_modules again via `npm install` and the tests worked again!

Comment: node version 14.15.1 worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I had similar issue after migration to ESLint my project.

I got rid of `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`.

Neither of the Node.JS version didn't solve the problem but somehow I found this post https://ievgen.de/2020/11/17/angular-tests-fail-docker/ which is basically saying to add the following line into your `karma.conf.js`:

```
proxies: {
  '/assets/': '/base/src/assets/'
},
```

This solve my problem :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to change your global `node` version, you can install a local version and run that instead. This way you will get absolute control over what you are running, regardless of the system you are running on.

```bash
yarn add node@^14.15.0 --dev
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/node/bin/node node_modules/.bin/ng test"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps a little!

Answer (score 5):

It's indeed an issue with karma on node v15. Looks like (for now) it will not be fixed, so downgrading to v14 is the solution: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3571

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

- In html use relative paths starting with `assets/...`. In component based CSS use relative paths going one level up: `../assets/...`
- Never, and I mean never use asset paths starting with a slash like `/assets` this will break your code in *some* cases
- Follow the advice below for configuring `karma.conf.js`  because karma does not serve assets and currently karma 5.1.1 with webpack 4.44.2 or some plugin of it crashes with OPs error above

## Post Mortem (3)

*I deleted my first post mortem twice now, because it was broken and lead me to a post mortem (3) :D*

Two things are important: You need to tweak the `karma.conf.js` as explained in the this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089721/2416394).

Add

```js
    proxies: {
      '/assets/': '/base/src/assets/'
      '/Every-single-image-from-css.png': '/base/src/assets/what-ever-the-path-is/Every-single-image-from-css.png'
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/assets/**', watched: false, included: false, nocache: false, served: true }
    ],
```

in the `config.set({` part, and yes, keep `/base/src/assets` even if `base` is nowhere to be found.
The second part is the file pattern you *need* to currently make things work with relative paths. The third part is actually the second entry in the `proxies` array: List every single resource accessed from css individually :/

### Important

`ng` preprocesses paths [somehow strange](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19664), the code above will result in your assets referenced from CSS will be *duplicated* and lying around in root once `ng build` completes. Very ugly but I don't know a solution to this except using images only from html, which gets processed correctly.
The thing I noticed `ng serve` flattens all urls. So even a css file looking like this

```css
.my-img{
  background: url('../assets/deeply/nested/logo.png');
}
```

will be served as `/logo.png` from the built-in webserver. I checked this while looking at the website produced by `ng serve` and inspecting network calls.

What ever this behaviour is, `ng test` will die because of this unless you do specify **every single** image in the proxies part.
Using the first proxies entry, e.g. `/assets/` is fun but works only when you would use absolute paths from assets, which you should not but is also used, when you reference images from within html, so **keep** it!

As the ng compilation flattens the urls, this proxy wont work for css references since even in `ng test` the images from css will be requested from root as `/logo.png` (stripped of their path). Unfortunately `proxies` does not support wildcards, otherwise one could write things like /*.png` to something. But currently listing all entries separately seems to be the solution.

## Why using absolute paths in assets is a stupid idea

My first result was to actually recommend to use path like
`/assets/foo.png`. Doing this, only the mentioned `proxies` entry is necessary (but it had to look a bit different).
Now I thought i was ok, because `ng serve` worked, `ng test` worked and even `ng build` worked.

But things went south when I wanted to deploy my angular app into a subdirectory. If you do this, I was unable to find any way, meddling around with `ng build --base-href '..'` and mixing also some `--deploy-url` into it to make things work.

**When you use absolute paths to your assets, never expect to make things work in a subdirectory.**

So you might be lucky using my "broken" approach in some instances but I kid you not, you are very likely to save some time following the excellent advise from [@programmerinprogress](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2482215/programmerinprogress) which I repeated above.

Comment: Had this error with a single spec file for an Angular component.  It was driving me crazy as all other specs ran fine.  Found this post and commented out the `<img>` element that uses `assets` in the template and the spec ran successfully.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: Had this error and all I did was altered the karma.conf.js as per [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089721/2416394), as you mentioned it was a much more elegant solution without changing the url paths in the CSS

Comment: thanks for sharing and updating the post! it is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This issue will happen if you use node:latest and also for node:14, this is because it happens for v14.15.2. As mentioned in the above answers, you should use node:14.15.1 and the issue will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:
`browsers: ['Chrome']` to `karma.conf.js`